# AWS boto3 view file in browser

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For AWS S3 and Python/Flask/Boto3, how do I view my file in my browser instead of directly downloading it?

I have something like this:

```
@app.route('/dl')
def dl():
  bucketName = "uw-note-share"
  key = "question4.png"
  s3.Bucket(bucketName).download_file(key, 'my_local_image.jpg')
  return "truu"
```

But this **downloads** the file into my disk location, what if I just want to view the file in the browser like a image link online?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'bucket-name',
        'Key': 'key-name'
    }
)
response = requests.get(url)
```

Source: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-urls

Comment: I am getting: `'s3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'generate_presigned_url'
`

Comment: That you could raise another bug with detailed logs.